# Mongodb Roll back in replica set

Tags: mongodb

Suppose you have a three node replica set. Node 1 is the primary. Node 2 is a secondary, Node 3 is a secondary running with a delay of 10 seconds. All writes to the database are issued with w=majority and j=1 (by which we mean that the getLastError call has those values set).

A write operation (could be insert or update) is initiated from your application at time=0. At time=5 seconds, the primary, Node 1, goes down for an hour and another node is elected primary.

Will there be a rollback of data when Node 1 comes back up? Choose the best answer.

1. Always yes
2. Always no
3. Maybe, it depends on whether Node 3 has processed the write.
4. Maybe, it depends on whether Node 2 has processed the write.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 5. depends on what other writes you have going and the replication lag between node 1 and node 2

Comment: Thanks sammaye.... what could be the best answer among the 4 options ??

Comment: A single write operation with no lag I would go for 2, by then the operation should be replicated to the new primary at time of failover I would reckon, especially with w=majority which I didn't see in my first comment, that should mean that 2/3 members should ack the write and since node 3 is delayed it shouldn't ack it right there.

Comment: This is a copy of a MongoDB exam question!

Comment: Because this is exact copy of the question from M101 Course, I think no answer should be given to the question. Instead we should give hints and links to materials from which we can get information on how to answer the question.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to change my answer to 4 however, it should be 2 with a w=majority. You could have an edge case whereby `wtimeout` on a operation is returned and the operation did not get acked by the majority of the set. These problems should be very rare or almost never happen, but something to keep in mind.

Since a majority of the nodes (1 & 2) will ack the write, if node 1 goes down node 2 should have its operations and be upto speed as such node 1 should not need to rollback to node 2's state; instead node 1 will play catch up.

Journal is not so important for defining whether a rollback would exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this relevant excerpt from MongoDB document: "A rollback **does not occur** if the write operations replicate to another member of the replica set ***before*** the primary steps down and if that member remains available and accessible to a majority of the replica set."

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a Question from a Mongo DB exam, but the answer is easy to see:

> Maybe, it depends on whether Node 2 has processed the write.